# Summarizing values in matrix with two different granularities

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a matrix that contains two different granularities.
In the image you can see
Deparment: second floor (first grain)
SubDepartment: Calendar days, patient days ( second grain)
Is there a way that I can make the highlighted rows in my image appear as empty or Null? Since that aggregation belongs to the first grain and not the second?
I was googling some things and I found some information about DAX functions. Has anybody ever run into something similar?

```
    BEFORE          

                    Target   Actual    Volume
Department            1200    1300         13
  Subdepartment 1     1200    1300          5
  Subdepartment 2     1200    1300          4
  Subdepartment 3     1200    1300          3
  Subdepartment 4     1200    1300          1
    AFTER           

                    Target   Actual    Volume
Department            1200    1300         13
  Subdepartment 1                           5
  Subdepartment 2                           4
  Subdepartment 3                           3
  Subdepartment 4                           1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [ISINSCOPE](https://dax.guide/isinscope/) function can be useful here.

Simple example:

```
IF ( ISINSCOPE ( Table1[Subdepartment] ), BLANK(), SUM ( Table1[Target] ) )
```